# MongoDB - How to use $bucketAuto aggregation where the buckets are grouped by another property

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to create an aggregation pipeline that return price ranges for each product category.

What I need to avoid is to load all available categories and call the `Database` again, one by one with a `$match` on each category. There must be a better way to do it.

Product documents

```
{
  Price: 500,
  Category: 'A'
},
{
  Price: 7500,
  Category: 'A'
},
{
  Price: 340,
  Category: 'B'
},
{
  Price: 60,
  Category: 'B'
}
```

Now I could use a `$group` stage to group the prices into an array by their category.

```
{
  _id: "$Category",
  Prices: {
    $addToSet: "$Price"
  }
}
```

Which would result in

```
{
  _id: 'A',
  Prices: [500, 7500]
},
{
  _id: 'B',
  Prices: [340, 60]
}
```

But If I use `$bucketAuto` stage after this, I am unable to `groupBy` multiple properties. Meaning it would not take the categories into account.

I have tried the following

```
{
  groupBy: "$Prices",
  buckets: 5,
  output: {
    Count: { $sum: 1}
  }
}
```

This does not take categories into account, but I need the generated buckets to be organised by category. Either having the category field within the `_id` as well or have it as another field and have 5 buckets for each distinct category:

```
{
  _id: {min: 500, max: 7500, category: 'A'},
  Count: 2
},
{
  _id: {min: 60, max: 340, category: 'B'},
  Count: 2
}...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1

- if you want to group by category and find the max and min price for that category you can do it like this

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62bdf89fbefa88fe45d75eb8)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": "$Category",
    "min-price": {"$min": "$Price"},
    "max-price": {"$max": "$Price"}}}])
```

Query2

- if you want to group by category and then apply the bucket inside the array of the prices, to create like 5 buckets like in your example
- you can do it with a trick, that allows us to use stage operators to  do operators inside the array
- the trick is to have 1 extra collection with only 1 document `[{}]`
- you do lookup, you unwind that array, you do what you want on it
- here we unwind the array and do $bucketAuto on it, with 5 buckets, like in your example, this way we can have group by category, and the prices in 5 ranges (5 buckets)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62be0ccfbefa88fe45d75eb9)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": {"_id": "$Category", "prices": {"$push": "$Price"}}},
 {"$lookup": 
   {"from": "coll_with_1_empty_doc",
    "pipeline": 
     [{"$set": {"prices": "$$prices"}}, {"$unwind": "$prices"},
       {"$bucketAuto": {"groupBy": "$prices", "buckets": 5}}],
    "as": "bucket-prices",
    "let": {"prices": "$prices", "category": "$_id"}}}])
```

If none of the above works, if you can give sample documents and example output

Comment: My goal was to use `bucketAuto` which your second example does very well. It would be even better if I would not need to created an empty collection just for this. Also for some reason if within the `group` I use a capital P for the field `prices`, it will not work even if I change it within the `set` operator too, to `$$Prices`, but that is not that important